# ZF1 user logged out when browser closed

Tags: php, zend-framework, session-cookies

I have the following code in my ZF1 application for logging users in:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $this->view->flashMessages = implode($this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages());
    $form = new Mmb_Form_Login();
    $this->view->form = $form;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
            $values = $form->getValues();
            Zend_Session::rememberMe(2592000);
            $adapter = new Mmb_Auth_Adapter_Doctrine($values['username'], $values['password']);

            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
            if ($result->isValid()) {
                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mmb.auth');
                $session->user = $adapter->getResultArray('password');
                $this->_redirect('/');
            } else {
                $this->view->message = 'Invalid Login';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've used Zend_Session::rememberMe(2592000) so that the session stays active for 30 days. From what I understand, the session should still be active even if the user closes their browser. Unfortunately, this is not what's happening; if you close the browser, you have to log in again.

What am I doing wrong? Is there also a chance that I need to adjust something in my php.ini file?

Comment: are you deleting cookies on closing your browser?

Comment: Well, I didn't think I was. I stayed logged in to every other website/web app out there on my computer. But trying my app on a different computer works fine--I stay logged in, as I should. Yet when I went into my Firefox settings, it said it was keeping my history and cookies. Very strange...

Comment: So the Problem only occurs in Firefox? Did you try a different browser on your machine?

Comment: Yeah, Chrome worked just fine. It seems like such a boneheaded thing not to check that first. But I still can't figure out why it's logging me out of my app and not everything else.